# Как показать изображение в wpf без маштабирования

Tags: wpf, изображения

Нужно что бы картинка не подгонялась под размер окна, а показывалась вся при помощи ScrollView. Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

А разве простой способ не работает?

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Source="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" Stretch="None"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Все давно работает, это просто я паникер.